# Jolt: Conditional placing value if boolean is true

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have this case where if defaultshipping is true, the phone should be placed into  shippingAddressBook->phone (same for billing). My transformation is close but the issue is that it is not grabbing the value of "phone".

Can someone help me with this please :)

Input:

```json
{
  "phone": "869-947-4444",
  "defaultshipping": false,
  "defaultbilling": true
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "billingAddressBook" : {
    "phone" : "869-947-4444"
  }
}
```

My transformation attempt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "defaultbilling": {
        "true": {
          "#phone": "billingAddressBook.phone"
        }
      },
      "defaultshipping": {
        "true": {
          "#phone": "shippingAddressBook.phone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're so close, just need to go 2 level up in order to reach the level of `phone` and grab the value through use of `@(2,phone)` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "defaultbilling": {
        "true": {
          "@(2,phone)": "billingAddressBook.phone"
        }
      },
      "defaultshipping": {
        "true": {
          "@(2,phone)": "shippingAddressBook.phone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks again Barbaros!! Do you know how to adapt this if we have the same input inside an array like: [ {phone, defaultS, defaultB}, {phone, defaultS, defaultB},... ] It'd be to apply the same transformation logic to each member.

Comment: you're welcome @NicolasJimenez have nice studies! You can get the desired result, if you wrap up with extra curly braces such as `"spec": {"*": {  the same as above }}` where sample input is `[
  {
    "phone": "869-947-4444",
    "defaultshipping": false,
    "defaultbilling": true
  },
  {
    "phone": "132-865-2222",
    "defaultshipping": true,
    "defaultbilling": false
  }
]`